# Not able to login untill i click the login button for the second time or after refreshing the page

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication

```
    onSubmit(formData) {
    this.submitted = true;
    const email = formData.value.email;
    const password = formData.value.password;
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
        return;
    } else {   
    return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);    
    })
```

Not able to login untill i click the login button for the second time or after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that formData has the same value of this.loginForm.
Try to do this:

```
onSubmit(formData) {

  if (formData.invalid) {
        return;
  } 

    this.submitted = true;
    const email = formData.value.email;
    const password = formData.value.password;
  
    return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);    
    })
}
```

or call onsubmit without passing any parameter, and try:

```
onSubmit() {

  if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
        return;
  } 

    this.submitted = true;
    const email = this.loginForm.value.email;
    const password = this.loginForm.value.password;
  
    return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);    
    })
}
```